# How do I make a frequency report in JAVA

Tags: java, report, frequency

the application is a simple hotel booking app, 
ShahHotels is the name of the class which contains all of the instances and roomsList is the arraylist ofShahhotels

getFacilities is a method to get what type of room is booked by a certain person

How do i make a frequency report of how many types of a certain room are booked in a hotel

my code so far

```
public String getYearsFrequencyReport(String id) {

        for(ShahHotels s : roomsList)
        {int a=0;
            if(id.equalsIgnoreCase(s.getFacilities()))
            {
                a=a+1;
                return s.getFacilities() + a;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your code supposed to do?

Comment: This is application specific question.How do you expect world know about your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you find the element which equals your id, you return... try something like

```
int count = 0;
for (ShahHotels s : roomsList) {
    if (id.equalsIgnoreCase(s.getFacilities()) {
         count++;
    }
}

return count;
```

edit: i have no idea what you're actually asking now that I read it over again